# Adjusting position of minipage

Tags: minipage

I have been trying to include some tike-diagrams into my pdf using `\includepdf{...}` of `standalone` outputs. However, when I do that it makes an entirely new page with the diagram. So I tried using the `minipage` environment and now I get something like this:[image]

I have written:

```
...
\begin{center}
    \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
        \includepdf[scale=0.4]{Q1-1/Q1-1.pdf}
    \end{minipage}
\end{center}
...
\begin{center}
    \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
        \includepdf[scale=0.4]{Q1-12/Q1-2.pdf}
    \end{minipage}
\end{center}
...
```

The images are overlapping each other and other parts of the document.

Any and all help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let suppose, that `/Q1-1.pdf` is an image file which we can include it by `\includegraphics` command. Than you can write:

```
\documentclass[demo]{article} % In real document delete "demo"
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}\centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{Q1-1/Q1-1.pdf}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}\centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{Q1-12/Q1-2.pdf}
    \end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

and get:

[image]